# How to make Google+ Login flow Holo Dark?

Tags: android, google-plus, android-theme

I have some weird issue, while all my application is `Holo Dark` styled and shows the dark design for all of its dialogs and other components that take its design from the base `Holo Dark`, the only exception is the `Google+ Login` flow in which I see this:

[image]

That is followed by my created dialog that looks as it should:

[image]

But this created a weird experience for the user.

**So the question is:** How can I specify for the Google+ flow to be Holo Dark as well?

Relevant code of the `LoginActivity`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.google_login_button:
        {
            CupsLog.i(TAG, "google_login_button -> onClick");

            if (App.getInstance().mPlusClient == null) {
                App.getInstance().mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this).setActions(visiblaeActivities).build();
            }
            mResolveOnFail = true;
            App.getInstance().mPlusClient.connect();
            break;
        }
        case R.id.skip_button:
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}


    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    CupsLog.i(TAG, "onActivityResult, requestCode: " + requestCode);
    switch (requestCode) 
    {
        case REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR:
        {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                mResolveOnFail = true;   
                App.getInstance().mPlusClient.connect();
            }
            break;
        }
        case REQUSET_TOKEN_PERMISSIONS_RESLOVE_ERR:
        {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && App.getInstance().mPlusClient.isConnected()) 
            {
                fetchAuthToken();
            }
            break;
        }
     }          
  }


    @Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    CupsLog.i(TAG, "onConnectionFailed -> result: " + result.toString() );
    //The user clicked the sign-in button already. Start to resolve
    // connection errors. Wait until onConnected() to dismiss the
    // connection dialog.

    if (result.hasResolution()) {
        CupsLog.i(TAG, "onConnectionFailed -> if result.hasResolution()" );
        if (mResolveOnFail) {
            try 
            {
                CupsLog.i(TAG, " onConnectionFailed -> result.startResolutionForResult(loginActivity, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);" );
                mResolveOnFail = false;
                //mDialog.dismiss();
                result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
            } 
            catch (SendIntentException e) 
            {
                CupsLog.i(TAG, "onConnectionFailed -> mPlusClient.connect(); " );
                App.getInstance().mPlusClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The theme that I use for my application is: `Theme.AppCompat` as the base parent with minor changes I had to put in.

Comment: Show us the relevant code.

Comment: @Ahmad, posted the relevant code.

Comment: Hmm the Accountchoser is displayed by the `PlusClient.Builder`, if I'm not mistaken, right?

Comment: the account chooser is displayed as a resolution after this line:  result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);